# Flex3 - Passing flashvars to the swf in the html wrapper

Tags: apache-flex, null, flash, flashvars

I'm having issues passing flashvars to my app's swf.

I'm using the default template provided by flex builder, where I added the flashvars as explained in adobe livedocs:

```
AC_FL_RunContent(
        "src", "playerProductInstall",
        "FlashVars", "MMredirectURL="+MMredirectURL+'&MMplayerType='+MMPlayerType+'&MMdoctitle='+MMdoctitle+'langStyle=Styles_jp.swf&langId=jp_JP&langSource=jp_JP.xml'+"",
        "width", "100%", ...

AC_FL_RunContent(
        "src", "SOD",
        "FlashVars", "langStyle=Styles_jp.swf&langId=jp_JP&langSource=jp_JP.xml",
        "width", "100%", ...

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            id="SOD" width="100%" height="100%"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
            <param name="movie" value="SOD.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <embed src="SOD.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
                FlashVars="langStyle=Styles_jp.swf&langId=jp_JP&langSource=jp_JP.xml"
```

I need to read the Application.application.parameters values at the preinitialize state of the application. 
It seems that at this stage, the flashvars are already known by the top level application.

Using firebug, I've put breakpoints in AC_OETags.js to see if AC_Generateobj gets the proper params and it does get it properly. The output str equals:

```
<embed src="SOD.swf" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" id="SOD" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7" name="SOD" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" FlashVars="langStyle=Styles_jp.swf&langId=jp_JP&langSource=jp_JP.xml" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" > </embed>
```

Despite the fact that the app does have the flashvars; when I try to get them at the preinitialize phase I get an error saying Application.application.parameters is null.

Would anyone have a clue of what I'm doing wrong... ?

Thanks in advance :)

---

@mgraph

This is the wrapper I have now:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="AC_OETags.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0px; overflow:hidden }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body scroll="no">
        <noscript>
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
                id="SOD" width="100%" height="100%"
                codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
                <param name="movie" value="SOD.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <embed src="SOD.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
                    width="100%" height="100%" name="SOD" align="middle"
                    play="true"
                    loop="false"
                    quality="high"
                    allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                </embed>
            </object>
        </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do:

```
....
<param name="FlashVars" value="langStyle=Styles_jp.swf&langId=jp_JP&langSource=jp_JP.xml" />
<embed src="SOD.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
                FlashVars="langStyle=Styles_jp.swf&langId=jp_JP&langSource=jp_JP.xml"><embed>
```

Comment: @BS_C3 do not use `default template provided by flex builder`

Comment: @BS_C3 creat new html file and add embed script `<embed src="SOD.swf" quality="h...></embed>`only

Comment: Actually, it's not that it's not working. I might be setting something wrong... I just modified the generated wrapper to get the simplest html wrapper structure. But it's not even connecting to the debugger. I'm gonna edit the question so that you can see what I have in the wrapper

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11308/discussion-between-bs-c3-and-mgraph)